# Can't run vagrant following chef instructions from ops-code page

Tags: chef-infra

I'm following this basic ops-code tutorial about using chef and this is what I'm getting when I'm on

```
$ vagrant init opscode-ubuntu-1204 https://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04-i386_chef-11.4.4.box --no-color

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- log4r (LoadError)
  from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  from /usr/bin/vagrant:2:in `<main>'
```

I've stuck on 'Converge the Node' https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/converge/ point 2.

What I'm missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Did Niel's answer work? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same issue today. Did you install vagrant using `$ sudo apt-get install vagrant`? The version that is currently in the Ubuntu 13.04 repo is `1.0.3`, but the latest version on the Vagrant download page is `1.2.7`. The ops-code instructions link to this page.

However, installing this package tries to [remove virtualbox-4.2](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1379). [This comment put me on the right track:](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1379#issuecomment-13871795)

```
# Remove older version of vagrant
$ sudo apt-get remove vagrant

# Install downloaded package without removing virtualbox
$ sudo dpkg -i vagrant_x86_64.deb
```

You may also need to add `/opt/vagrant/bin/` to your PATH.

I hope that helps!